# Solr order of values in a multiple value field

Tags: solr

Got a field with multiple values been stored from dynamic fields, this data comes in the right order in the input xml file, but when we do a search, the data comes in a complete different order. Is there a way to control this order?

Let me describe the process.
1- the input file comes with dynamic fields, which follow the pattern `*_foo`.
2- The solr takes the values from this dynamic fields been added and copy the value over to `allFoos`.
3- We search for the multi-value field, and analize its content.

We saw that the values stored in `allFoos` lose the order given by the input file.

This dummy data provides an example on how we are handling the fields, and the copy.
Then names of the fields and values where change to do the testing, but the resut is expected to be the same.

#### Schema

```
<dynamicField name="`*_foo`" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="`allFoos`" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true"/>
<copyField source="`*_foo`" dest="`allFoos`"/>
```

#### Input file

```
<add>
    <doc>
        <field name="field_1_foo" update="set">1</field>
        <field name="field_2_foo" update="set">2</field>
        <field name="field_3_foo" update="set">3</field>
        <field name="field_4_foo" update="set">4</field>
        <field name="field_5_foo" update="set">5</field>
        <field name="field_6_foo" update="set">6</field>
        <field name="field_7_foo" update="set">7</field>
        <field name="field_8_foo" update="set">8</field>
        <field name="field_9_foo" update="set">9</field>
        <field name="field_10_foo" update="set">10</field>
        <field name="field_11_foo" update="set">11</field>
        <field name="field_12_foo" update="set">12</field>
        <field name="field_13_foo" update="set">13</field>
        <field name="field_14_foo" update="set">17</field>
        <field name="field_15_foo" update="set">15</field>
        <field name="field_16_foo" update="set">16</field>
        <field name="field_17_foo" update="set">17</field>
        <field name="field_18_foo" update="set">18</field>
        <field name="field_19_foo" update="set">19</field>
        <field name="field_20_foo" update="set">20</field>
        <field name="field_21_foo" update="set">21</field>
        <field name="field_22_foo" update="set">21</field>
        <field name="field_23_foo" update="set">21</field>
        <field name="field_24_foo" update="set">21</field>
        <field name="field_25_foo" update="set">21</field>
    </doc>
</add>
```

#### Result

```
"allFoos": [ "3", "16", "25", "20", "19", "7", "21", "6", "13", "8", "5", "18", "24", "17", "23", "15", "4", "10", "12", "11", "2", "14", "22", "9", "1"]
```

The search result is the same every time, I have deleted and reinserted the same data several times, and it's always in this same order.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The field name in the response isn't the same as the field name when indexing. The XML for the add document is also wrong, as it's missing a `<doc<` element around the fields.. Are you sure that this is even being indexed? Check the server log for any errors if your indexing client (curl, etc) isn't spitting it out..

Comment: sorry I'm using dummy data since I can't post the real one, but the data is being loaded and indexed. The problem is with the order of the data when we are doing a search.
The response is the multi-value field. And there are no errors in the server.

Comment: You'll have to create a minimal example that actually show the problem. When you paste data that isn't coherent with the question and contain errors, it's _very_ hard to say anything useful. Multi-valued fields keep their sequence by default.

Comment: I modify a little the description to provide more context. Also we saw that if we insert directly into `allFoos` the order remains the same. The problem might be when copying over the fields from the dynamic field to the multi-value field.

Answer (score 1):

Yonik Seely sums it up nicely at the end of [this thread](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/quot-order-quot-question-on-solr-multi-value-field-td4027695.html):

> Order is guaranteed to be maintained for
>   values in a multi-valued field. Order of different fields is not
>   maintained.

So since you are copying 25 **different** fields into `allFoos` order is not guaranteed. `SolrInputDocument` is backed by a `LinkedHashMap` by default, but also has a constructor that accepts an arbitrary `Map<String,SolrInputField>`, which implies that ordering of fields within the document should not be relied upon.

```
  public SolrInputDocument() {
    _fields = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  }

  public SolrInputDocument(Map<String,SolrInputField> fields) {
    _fields = fields;
  }
```

As part of your document ingestion process, you could preprocess the data to produce a single field and add the values to that field in the proper order. The order within a single field should be maintained. This is best done in an external pipeline where you will be able to observe the original order in the source document. Perhaps if some sorting or other logic can reconstruct the proper order from the field names you could do it within Solr by installing a custom [`UpdateRequestProcessorFactory`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_3_1/solr-core/index.html) implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a stable and recommend option, using the [StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ScriptUpdateProcessor) processor. We are going to use Javascript to get all the fields and the values in the order we need. I am going to write this with some steps:

Your *schema.xml* will be the same, except the schema must not have the third line (about the copy fields: *...copyField source *_foo fields to allFoos field...*). This part will be delegate to Javascript code. It remains like this:

```
<dynamicField name="`*_foo`" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="`allFoos`" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

In the *solrconfig.xml* of your core, write this:

```
<!-- ... part of your solrconfig.xml ... -->

<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler"> 
    <lst name="defaults"> 
        <str name="update.chain">custom</str>
    </lst> 
</requestHandler>

<!-- ... part of your solrconfig.xml ... -->

<updateRequestProcessorChain name="custom">

    <processor class="solr.StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory">
        <str name="script">update-script.js</str>
        <lst name="params">
            <str name="config_param">example config parameter</str>
        </lst>
    </processor>

    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />

</updateRequestProcessorChain>

<!-- ... part of your solrconfig.xml ... -->
```

With this, we are telling Solr to use the chain plugin 'custom', an URP ([Update Request Processor](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor)) self-customized that use the *StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory* processor when you use the 'update' request handler. If you are using other request handler, set this in the request handler desired.

You must have an '*update-script.js*' file already at the same level folder of your 'conf' core directory, with all the functions you should need and some examples commented.

In the function processAdd(cmd) of this *update-script.js* file, write this:

```
doc = cmd.solrDoc;  // org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument
id = doc.getFieldValue("id");
logger.info("update-script#processAdd: id = " + id);

fieldNames = doc.getFieldNames().toArray();

for (var i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {

    fieldValue = doc.getFieldValue(fieldName[i]);
    doc.addField("allFoos", String(fieldValue.toString()));
}
```

This is processed before any ingested/updated field data in Solr (this part of execution delegates on RunUpdateProcessorFactory).

All done.